# How make to flow around a triangular block?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two block. One of them triangular shaped. How make to flow around this div text? Example:
[image]
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="entry-cover">Triangle</div>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda autem ex 
           labore, repellat saepe soluta suscipit vel veniam.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS has no!

Comment: Can you add the complete code both HTML and CSS

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far...

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `css shapes`. Read this http://webplatform.adobe.com/shapes/.

You have to know that it's not cross browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

**EDIT** - there is polyfill by Adobe, check this out.

https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill

So if your website need to cross browsers, you have to layout it with css (padding, margin, etc.) or spaces.

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use skew to the div which contains text. , might help. Other solution : You can use  &nbsp

Comment: How is that supposed to be an answer?